# Perl QtCore4 won't install

Tags: perl, qt, cmake, cpan, qwt

I can't build the QtCore4 package, I get an error regarding "SMOKE_QWT_LIBRARY" not being set during make. I'm running perlbrew Perl 5.14.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I've tried manually building the module as well as through CPAN, and also installing on system Perl (also 5.14.2) and perl 5.16.1. I've looked in the files in the directory referenced in the error message. The file CMakeLists.txt contains the reference to "SMOKE_QWT_LIBRARY" but there is no directory reference or obvious way to re-configure the file (and I'm not sure what to reconfigure it to!).

Can anyone help with this please?

This is the make output:
    Running install for module 'QtCore4'
    Running make for C/CB/CBUREL/Qt4-0.99.0.tar.bz2
    Checksum for /home/sillymoose/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CB/CBUREL/Qt4-
    0.99.0.tar.bz2 ok

```
  CPAN.pm: Building C/CB/CBUREL/Qt4-0.99.0.tar.bz2

-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found Perl: /home/sillymoose/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-
5.14.2/bin/perl 
-- Found PerlLibs: /home/sillymoose/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-
5.14.2/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/libperl.a (found version "5.14.2")
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.1")
-- Found QScintilla2: /usr/lib/libqscintilla2.so
-- Found QImageBlitz: /usr/include/qimageblitz 
-- Phonon Version: 4.6.0
-- Found Phonon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libphonon.so
-- Found Phonon Includes: /usr/include/qt4/KDE;/usr/include/qt4
-- Found Qwt: /usr/lib/libqwt-qt4.so
-- Perl headers found: /home/sillymoose/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-
5.14.2/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/CORE
-- Perl headers found: /home/sillymoose/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-
5.14.2/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/CORE
-- Build PerlQt bindings: 
Phonon;QImageBlitz;QScintilla;Qt3Support;QtDBus;QtDeclarative;QtGui;QtHe
lp;QtNetwork;QtOpenGL;QtScript;QtSql;QtSvg;QtTest;QtUiTools;QtWebKit;QtX
ml;QtXmlPatterns;Qwt
-- Skip PerlQt bindings: QtMultimedia

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----
-- The following external packages were located on your system.
-- This installation will have the extra features provided by these 
packages.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----
   * QScintilla2 - QScintilla2 libraries
   * QImageBlitz - QImageBlitz library
   * Phonon - Phonon multimedia framework
   * Qwt5 for Qt4 - Qwt5 libraries for Qt4

------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----
-- Congratulations! All external packages have been found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they 
are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the 
CMake files:
SMOKE_QWT_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "perl_qwt" in directory 
/home/sillymoose/.cpan/build/Qt4-0.99.0-5Qxy7L/qwt/src

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
No 'Makefile' created  CBUREL/Qt4-0.99.0.tar.bz2
  /home/sillymoose/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/bin/perl Makefile.PL 
-- NOT OK
```

And this is the contents of ~/.cpan/build/Qt4-0.99.0-5Qxy7L/qwt/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/qtcore/src
    ${PERL_INCLUDE_PATH}
    ${QT_INCLUDES} )

# Run doxsubpp.pl to run xsubpp on Qwt.xs
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Qwt.c
                   COMMAND ${PERL_EXECUTABLE} ARGS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/qtcore/src/doxsubpp.pl ${PERL_EXECUTABLE} Qwt.xs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Qwt.c
                   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Qwt.xs
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
# Make sure we build Qwt.c as c++ code
set_source_files_properties( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Qwt.c 
    PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX
)

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${PERL_CXX_FLAGS} )

set(qwt_LIBRARY_SRC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Qwt.c
    qwthandlers.cpp
)

if(WIN32)
    set(libraryName PerlQwt)
else()
    set(libraryName Qwt)
endif(WIN32)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/blib/arch/auto/${libraryName})
add_library(perl_qwt SHARED ${qwt_LIBRARY_SRC})

target_link_libraries(perl_qwt
    ${SMOKE_QWT_LIBRARY}
    perlqtcore4)

set_target_properties(perl_qwt PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${libraryName})
set_target_properties(perl_qwt PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

install(TARGETS perl_qwt DESTINATION ${CUSTOM_PERL_SITE_ARCH_DIR}/auto/${libraryName}/)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved on [a thread on Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1001357). See thread for details. However it involves:

1. Installing the correct source libraries.
2. Re-compiling Perl with the correct C flag.
3. Compiling the module from source.

NB. Could only get this to run on Perl v5.10.1.